# How to force a line break on a Javascript concatenated string?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I'm sending variables to a text box as a concatenated string so I can include multiple variables in on getElementById call.

**I need to specify a line break so the address is formatted properly.**

```
document.getElementById("address_box").value = 
(title + address + address2 + address3 + address4);
```

I've already tried \n after the line break and after the variable. and tried changing the concatenation operator to +=.

***Fixed***: This problem was resolved using;

```
document.getElementById("address_box").value = 
(title + "\n" + address + "\n" + address2 + "\n" +  address3 +  "\n" + address4);
```

**and changing the textbox from 'input type' to 'textarea'**

Comment: I would have up-voted this question however you accepted a not-an-answer as an answer. ︎

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't have multiple lines in a text box, you need a textarea. Then it works with `\n` between the values.

Answer (score 25):

```
document.getElementById("address_box").value = 
(title + "\n" + address + "\n" + address2 + "\n" + address3 + "\n" + address4);
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `\n` inside quotes.

`document.getElementById("address_box").value = (title + "\n" + address + "\n" + address2 + "\n" + address3 + "\n" + address4)`

`\n` is called a `EOL` or `line-break`, `\n` is a common `EOL` marker and is commonly refereed to as `LF` or `line-feed`, it is a special `ASCII` character

Answer (score 6):

Using **Backtick**

Backticks are commonly used for multi-line strings or when you want to interpolate an expression within your string

```js
let title = 'John';
let address = 'address';
let address2 = 'address2222';
let address3 = 'address33333';
let address4 = 'address44444';
document.getElementById("address_box").innerText = `${title} 
${address}
${address2}
${address3} 
${address4}`;
```

```html
<div id="address_box">
</div>
```