# How to add new line in jQuery function text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert new line in jQuery function.

```
$.ajax({ 
        url:"http: //192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/api.php", 
        type:"GET", 
        dataType:"json", 
        data:{type:"login", UserName:userId,Password:userPassword}, 
        ContentType:"application/json", 
        success: function(response){                        
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));                                   
              var detailsDiv=$("div#details");
              var userName=response[0].User.UserName;                              
              var ID=response[0].User.Followers;
              var Email=response[0].User.email;
              var Dish=response[0].User.Dish;                              
             detailsDiv.text("UserName: "+userName+"ID: "+ID+"Email: "+Email+"Dish: "+Dish);
         },
```

Check the following line in above code: `detailsDiv.text("UserName: "+userName+"ID: "+ID+"Email:"+Email+"Dish: "+Dish);` 
It is giving output like: `UserName: Ravi ID: 123 Email:ravi@gmail.com Dish: Indian Dishes`

**I want output like**

```
UserName: Ravi  
ID: 123  
Email:ravi@gmail.com  
Dish: Indian Dishes
```

Comment: `detailsDiv.html("UserName: "+userName+"<br />ID: "+ID+"<br />Email:"+Email+"<br />Dish: "+Dish);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a line break on a Javascript concatenated string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357846/how-to-force-a-line-break-on-a-javascript-concatenated-string)

Comment: Did you really need to show all that Ajax code just to ask about displaying newlines?

Comment: This is clearly not a duplicate of the linked question, but shows a misunderstanding of browsers' rendering in a similar vain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.text` to `.html` and use `<br>` element, it inserts a line break:

```
detailsDiv.html("UserName: "+userName+"<br>ID: "+ID+"<br>Email: "+Email+"<br>Dish: "+Dish);
//                                      ^^            ^^                  ^^
```

If you are writing XHTML, then the `<br>` tag must be closed, like this `<br />`:

```
detailsDiv.html("UserName: "+userName+"<br />ID: //...
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this solution because using `$.html` implies that characters "printed" in the destination wouldn't be sanitized, actually converted to text.

Comment: So? Sanitize, then add line breaks, then print.

Comment: Well a solution like @Deena's would be optimal but using `$.text` not `$.html`

Answer (score 2):

**Try this...**

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url:"http: //192.168.1.4/Experiements/webservices/api.php", 
        type:"GET", 
        dataType:"json", 
        data:{type:"login", UserName:userId,Password:userPassword}, 
        ContentType:"application/json", 
        success: function(response){                        
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));                                   
              var detailsDiv=$("div#details");
              var userName=response[0].User.UserName;                              
              var ID=response[0].User.Followers;
              var Email=response[0].User.email;
              var Dish=response[0].User.Dish;                              
            $("#username").html(userName);
            $("#userid").html(ID);
            $("#email").html(Email);
            $("#dish").html(Dish);
         },
});
```

HTML:

```
         <p id="username"></p>
         <p id="userid"></p>
         <p id="email"></p>
         <p id="dish"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `p` elements for example and [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method:

```
detailsDiv.append('<p>UserName: ' + userName + '</p>');
detailsDiv.append('<p>ID: ' + ID + '</p>');
detailsDiv.append('<p>Email: ' + Email + '</p>');
detailsDiv.append('<p>Dish: ' + Dish + '</p>');
```