# Render a new line from a text interpolation in Angular 4 / Ionic 3

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, string-interpolation

I have the following front code:

```
<p>{{ news.content }}</p>
```

`news.content` is stored in my firebase DB.

How can I render a new line in this text interpolation without modifying my front code (nor HTML nor CSS)? I will eventually change my front code if needed but I need I quick backend fix because my app is in prod and I cannot not provide an update within the day...

So I tried `\n`, `<br />` and `&#13;&#10;` but none is working...

When I inspect the view, HTML is as follows:

```
<p>"my text"</p>
```

So I guess the pain point comes from the double quotes...

Just for you to know, I need this to work on the iOS build.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood, you want to be able to render a new line, thanks to the object you gor from your component.

So I think you shoud use `[innerHTML]` of Angular and the `<br>` tag (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#property-binding-or-interpolation-) :

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent{
    sometext = 'some text';
    anothertext = '<br>new line here';
   ...
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p>{{sometext}} and <span [innerHTML]="anothertext"></span></p>
```

Comment: Indeed that's a good solution but I am not able to change my front-end code right now... I mean I have to submit an update to Apple and it will take 24-48h but I need to fix it for today. So I was wondering if there is any special character that would make the trick meanwhile... As text is the only element that I can modify right now...

Comment: Is there an id to your html element, or a way to identify it ?

Comment: No no id. What was your thought ?

Comment: Maybe with some javascript code you could have done it by getting the element : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357846/how-to-force-a-line-break-on-a-javascript-concatenated-string