# How can I frame a string with asterisks?

Tags: javascript

I try to build a function that will frame me a string with asterisks, using only JS.
How can I do it?

`function frame('Good Morning')`

should get >>>

```
****************
* Good Morning *
****************

Edit after having to see some answers - the main problem was to break the line of asterisks so it will look as in the example, and not just long lines of asterisks.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a line break on a Javascript concatenated string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357846/how-to-force-a-line-break-on-a-javascript-concatenated-string)

Comment: Thank you for all the answers - it seems that my problem was to understand how to break the lines of asterisks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you should calculate the length of the string and use that with [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) to make the borders:

```js
function frame(str){
    let border = '*'.repeat(str.length + 4)
    return `${border}\n* ${str} *\n${border}`
}

console.log(frame('Good Morning'))
console.log(frame('A longer string with more words'))
```

If you want to be a little crazier, you can split on new lines and accept multi-line input. This uses [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to build the inner strings and [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to pad with spaces:

```js
function frame(str){
    let lines = str.split('\n')
    // get length of longest line:
    let max_length = Math.max(...lines.map(l => l.length))
    let border = '*'.repeat(max_length + 4)

    let ret =  border + "\n"
    // make inner lines padded to length:
    ret += lines.reduce((s,l) => s+=`* ${l.padEnd(max_length)} *\n`, "")
    ret += border
    return ret
}

console.log(frame('Good Morning'))
console.log(frame('A longer string with more words'))
console.log(frame('A longer string with more words\nand more lines\nwrapped into a nice box.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

EDIT

```js
    function frame(str){
        var border="";
        for(i=0;i<str.length+4;i++){
            border += "*"
        }
        return border + "\n* "+str+" *\n" + border;
        
    }
    console.log(frame("Hello World"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I did that before edit was made to the question

Comment: The only problem is that the asterisks in the beginning and in the end are not the line above and below.

Comment: Okay, now I see after you edit it. Thank you it is working almost perfect, I need to clean there something, but in general, I understood now how to jump between the lines.